# Copy to clipboard in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to make copy to clipboard. It's working on div element but if i use it in datatable that time not working

here is my code

```
->editColumn('value', function ($data) {
            return '<span>'.$data->value.'</span> <i class="fa fa-copy" title="Copy to Clipboard" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="copyToClipboard(this,'.$data->value.')"></i>';
        })

  function copyToClipboard(em,text) {
            var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
            dummy.style.display = 'none'
            document.body.appendChild(dummy);
            dummy.value = text;
            dummy.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            document.body.removeChild(dummy);
            $(em).attr('data-original-title', 'Copied')
                .tooltip('fixTitle')
                .tooltip('show');
        }
```

it shows **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list** . How can i fix ?

Comment: Please post pure HTML and JS in a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: So does whatever text you are copying have a quote in it?

Comment: LOOK at the generated HTML and see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this to not have issues with content

```
->editColumn('value', function ($data) {     
  return '<span>'.$data->value.'</span> <i class="fa fa-copy" title="Copy to Clipboard" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>';
  })
```

using

```
$('.fa-copy').on('click', function() {
  copyToClipboard(this,$(this).prev().text());
})
```

you cannot have display none on the textarea if you want to create a copy

```js
$('.fa-copy').on('click', function() {
  const text =  $(this).prev().text();
  console.log(text)
  copyToClipboard(this, $(this).prev().text());
})

function copyToClipboard(em, text) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
 // dummy.style.display = 'none'; // cannot be display none
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  dummy.value = text;
  dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
//  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
//  $(em).attr('data-original-title', 'Copied')
//    .tooltip('fixTitle')
//    .tooltip('show');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" >
<span>Data value from span</span> <i class="fa fa-copy" title="Copy to Clipboard" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but not working.... nothing happened

Comment: “Not working” is a USELESS comment. Console errors ? What? Show a [mcve] like we ask do we can help you better

Comment: I said **nothing happened** . no error shows

Comment: @Kabir Works for me if I remove all the stuff you did not bother to show us AND make the text area display

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what is wrong. There is a missing closing parenthesis here

`->editColumn('value', function ($data) { return '<span>'.$data->value.'</span> <i class="fa fa-copy" title="Copy to Clipboard" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="copyToClipboard(this,'.$data->value.')"></i>'; })`

Comment: still same error.....